# Space too wide between index and section in table of content for second page

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, indexing, report, section-titles

I've change the space beetween the index and the section(the number and the title of the section) in the first page of the table of content but it doesn't apply to the second page... What can I do?

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.8em}{1.8em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.3em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents{}
```

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. And, which LaTeX packages (if any) do you load that influence the layout of headers and the appearance of the table of contents? Please also clarify what you mean by "index" -- the header line, maybe?

Comment: Hi I updated the question!

Comment: I use a tone of packages but I think those only influence the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the second page of the ToC it is that you have not allowed enough space for numbers such as `13.1`. If you are changing the layout of the ToC (or LoF or LoT) I suggest that you use the `tocloft` package as below.

```
% tocspaceprob.tex  SE 572798

\documentclass[french]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{comment}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.8em}{1.8em}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{2}{2.3em}{2.3em}} % this works
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.3em}{2.3em}} % change this
\makeatother
\end{comment}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % use this for French
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.3em} % more space for section numbers
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3.3em} % more space for subsection numbers

\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{Early section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\setcounter{section}{12}
\section{Later section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]